# ECLiPSe Prolog - Unexpected behaviour of 'nonvar/1'

Tags: prolog

I was going through some ECLiPSe documentation and found this:

```
`nonvar/1` : Fails if Term is not instantiated
```

I tried doing this:

```
1. Query: nonvar(X). Result: No (AS EXPECTED)
2. Query: X=5, nonvar(X). Result: Yes (AS EXPECTED)
3. Query: X=5, nonvar(f(X)). Result: Yes, X=5. (AS EXPECTED)
```

Now this query result confused me:

```
4. Query: nonvar(f(X)). Result: Yes, X=X.
```

Queries 1,2,3 work as expected. To me, the result of 4 is weird. As per the documentation of nonvar/1 in eclipse, the argument can be ANY PROLOG TERM (so, f(X) is fine), and nonvar tests if the argument is INSTANTIATED or not.

In the case of 4, it is not instantiated so it should be NO and not YES (X=X). Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect, or is it a documentation issue in ECLiPSe prolog? I am using the latest version.

Thanks!

Comment: @mescalinum: This is in no way specific to Eclipse-Prolog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query 4, `f(X)` *contains* the non-instantiated variable `X` but it *is not itself* an uninstantiated variable.

SWI-Prolog's help is perhaps a bit clearer on the meaning of `nonvar`:

> `nonvar(Term)`: True if `Term` currently is not a free variable.

You can check whether a term contains free variables with `ground/1`:

```
?- X = 5, ground(f(X)).
X = 5.

?- ground(f(X)).
false.
```

Comment: @larsmans- Please correct me if I am wrong - Isnt a structure like f(X,Y) also a term that is by itself a free variable?

Comment: so, using var and non-var, we should NOT be testing for compound terms, is that the meaning?

Comment: @kallakafar: a compound term is never a variable. It may contain variables, but it isn't one itself.